# How to move the Child Classes into their respective files and build them as Shared Objects in Linux using CPP

Tags: c++

I was trying to implement Shared Objects so before that, I was trying to experiment with that and I got stuck in the following.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Animal{
    public:
        virtual void walk(void)=0;
};
class Human : public Animal{
    public:
        void walk(void){
            cout<<"Hi I am a human-being. I have only 2 legs!"<<endl;
        }
};
```

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Animal{
    public:
        virtual void walk(void)=0;
};
class Tiger : public Animal{
    public:
        void walk(void){
            cout<<"Hi I am a Tiger. I have only 4 legs!"<<endl;
        }
};
```

So these are the 2 child classes in two separate files which I have named as "Tiger.cpp" and "Human.cpp"
and I have compiled them as "g++ -shared -fPIC -o libTiger.so Tiger.cpp" and for the other also.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Human.cpp"
#include "Tiger.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main(void){
    Animal *aptr; // Declaring a pointer var. of type Animal class
    Human hobj; // Declaring an obj. of type Human
    Tiger tobj; // Declaring an obj. of type Tiger
    
    aptr = &hobj; // Assigning the addr. of Human object into aptr;
    aptr->walk(); // Will call the Human version of walk();
    
    aptr = &tobj;
    aptr->walk(); // Will call the Tiger version of walk();
    return 0;
}
```

Now when I tried to build the main() function using g++ it's showing an error as the Animal class is getting defined twice so I understood that and then I tried to move the Parent class into a separate header file and included that in the two-child class and removed from the main file but that's approach is also not working.
The error that is:

```
++ Animal.cpp -L/home//sugatak99/POC/ -llibrary -o Animal
In file included from Animal.cpp:3:
Tiger.cpp:3:7: error: redefinition of ‘class Animal’
    3 | class Animal{
      |       ^~~~
In file included from Animal.cpp:2:
Human.cpp:3:7: note: previous definition of ‘class Animal’
    3 | class Animal{
      |
```

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description. Please [edit] to quote any errors received in full.

Comment: you should NEVER write `using namespace std;` in a header file!

Comment: You need to open your C++ textbook to two chapters. The first chapter explains what header files are, how they work, and how to include header files in your program. The second chapter is the one that explains the One Definition Rule. After reading both chapters you will learn everything that's needed to do this program. Unfortunately, stackoverflow.com is not a replacement for a C++ textbook, so you'll need to be referred there for more explanation. You are asking about basic C++ fundamentals, so you will find a better explanation in your textbook than in one/two paragraphs on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sam Varshavchik is totally right!